# Angular http RXJS observable not invoking error callbacks

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have an angular project, which is using RXJS observables. Everything is fine unless I have to deal with error handling, but when the API returns errors the error callback is never being called.

```
 this.http
  .post(url, registerFormData)
  .pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return throwError(err);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(
    (res) => console.log('HTTP response', res),
    (err) => console.log('HTTP Error', err),
    () => console.log('HTTP request completed.')
  );


// package.json
"@angular/animations": "^10.0.14",
"@angular/common": "~10.0.5",
"@angular/compiler": "~10.0.5",
"@angular/core": "~10.0.5",
"@angular/forms": "~10.0.5",
"@angular/localize": "~10.0.5",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.5",
"@angular/router": "~10.0.5",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
"fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
"ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^13.0.0",
"rxjs": "~6.5.5",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"
```

Comment: What `console.log` output do you get?

Comment: None, it's not even invoking

Comment: have you written any unit tests we can check?, is it actually throwing the exception?

Comment: No, I had created the trouble myself.. Turns out that my token interceptors, intercepts all http errors and didn't return error observable properly, so that didn't invoke error callbacks in the subscribe methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for this, but I managed to find the solution by myself.

If the admins think this is handy let it be here as it may help somebody else, if not it can be deleted.

So I had an interceptor for http errors and didn't return properly the error observable, so it must have failed somewhere on the pipe functions. The strange thing is that neither RXJS throwed errors if the error object is missing, neither angular threw errors about that.

```
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
```

constructor(
private storage: StorageService,
private notificator: NotificationService
) {}

public intercept(request: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler) {
const token = this.storage.get('token') || '';

```
const updatedRequest = request.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
  responseType: 'text',
});

return next.handle(updatedRequest).pipe(
  catchError((err: any) => {
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
      this.notificator.error(
        'Session expired, you are being redirected to home screen'
      );
      this.storage.remove('token');
      this.storage.remove('user');

      setTimeout(() => {
        location.reload();
      }, 1000);
    }
    // return of([err]); // not working ...
    return throwError(err); // this is now working as throwError returns the 
    proper error observable, which invokes the error callback in subsribe 
    callbacks. 
  })
);
```

}
}

Comment: you could just create an [http-interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) instead of catching the error in the request service or in the request itself